# Why is $n \log \log n$ not tightly bounded by $n$?

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

I don't understand why $n \log \log n $ is not $\Theta (n)$.

Suppose we give $n$ a value of $10,000$. Then $n \log \log n$ is $6020.6$. So isn't $n \log \log n$ upper- and lower-bounded by $n$, as $n \log \log n \geq Cn$?

Comment: Hi, I thought 10000(log(log 10000)) is 6020.6?

Comment: Because log 10000 = 4. so it becomes 10000(log(4)) right?

Comment: There is _no_ constant $C$ such that $n \log \log n < C n$, as there is no constant $C$ such that $\log \log n < C$ _for all_ $n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As $n$ grows bigger, the ratio between $n\log\log n$ and $n$, namely $\log\log n$, tends to infinity. Hence it is not possible to upper bound $n\log\log n \leq Cn$ for any constant $C$. If you stare at this inequality, you discover that the constant $C$ must satisfy $\log\log n \leq C$ for all $n$, yet the function $\log\log n$ is not bounded.

Comment: Hi, I understood most of your explanation, but can you give me a value of n and C where $n\log\log n \leq Cn$ is false?

Comment: No matter what value I give n, $n\log\log n \leq Cn$ seems to hold. 1,000,000 log log 1,000,000 <=1*1,000,000.

Comment: Got it, didn't give n a large enough value! Thanks! =)

Comment: For any given value of $C$, take any $n$ larger than $10^{10^C}$. The point you're missing is that the *same* value of $C$ has to work for *all* $n$.

Answer (score 4):

You could not narrow $f(x) = x\log \log x$  with $ g = n $, because inequalities that must be met for this, never occur. Remember that the logarithm function is always increasing.
So, If We had it, $f$ should perform the next inequalite for some constants $c$ and $C$.
$$ cn\leq f \leq Cn$$

Let's see that, for example a right side of these inequalities and see the contradiction.

$$
\begin{align}
x\log \log x \leq cx\\
e^{x\log \log x }\leq e^{cx}\\
e^x\log x \leq e^{cx}\\
\log x \leq e^c
\end{align}
$$
So, you are saying that $\log x \leq k$, for any $x\in R$, that's not true.

Comment: Hi, I understood most of your explanation, but can you give me a value of n and C where $n \log \log n \leq Cn$ is false?

Comment: If I have 1 for the C value, the statement $ n \log \log n \leq Cn$ always seems to be true! Am I missing something?

Comment: @MalcolmX: For $C=1$, pick $n = 10^{100}$, since you seem to be assuming the $\log$ is to base $10$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, because $\log\log n$ is **not** a constant! actually,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \log\log n = \infty$$

while for some function to be $\Theta(n)$ it is required that it is bounded by $cn$ for some **constant** $c$.

**tl;dr** you didn't look at large enough $n$'s. try $n$ = [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).

Comment: Well, $f(n) = 1$ if $n$ is prime, otherwise $f(n) = 2$ is not constant either, but $n f(n) = \theta(n)$.

Comment: @Aryabhata you are right, but I said "*bounded* by a constant". $c=3$ works for your example (as an upper bound).

Comment: Got it, thanks! :) I will upvote your answer when I can!

Comment: I was only disputing the first statement which does not have the word bounded in it :-)